# Need to Send then Receive and Display Image using URI

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, uri

I need to create two apps, one which allows you select a image file from the device and send it using an intent.  My code for this is:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

This code appears to be working because if I use gmail as my desitination it seems to work fine.

My problems seem to be in the Recieve app I cannot get the image to display, Ive tried using BitmapFactory, creating drawable etc.  They always come up null.  I have even put the following code into my send app:

```
                Uri imageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
                String string = imageURI.toString();
                string = string.replace("file://", "");
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(string);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
                iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

which displays the image fine, but when the code is put into the recieve app d becomes null.

My recieve code currently is as follows:

```
  private void handleSendImage(Intent intent) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (uri != null) {
            iv.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does `file` point? If it is external storage (which it should be), does the receiving app have the manifest and runtime permissions for that? Note that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` only has meaning for `content` `Uri` values, not `file` ones.

Comment: The file points to for example ""/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170326_140149.jpg""

Comment: That is external storage. Does the receiving app hold either `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions, including handling runtime permissions on Android 6.0+?

Comment: THANK YOU I was missing the runtime permission...